# Mod_Rewrite Htaccess Internal Redirect Just Not Working

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have tried so many things in the past hour and nothing works.
I have a website called example.com
I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ index.php?p=$1&i=$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

When I go on example/forums/discussion-f3.html it works.
When I try /forums/introductions-f2.html, it redirects me to /index.php/?p=forums&i=introductions-f2. Also, http://craftshaft.org/forums/ sends me to http://craftshaft.org/index.php/?p=forums but when I do it without the slash and remove it from the code, it works, but I need the slash at the end so it looks like a folder.

**Basically, I'd like to be able to view URLs like this:**

- /forums.html (to /index.php?p=forums)
- forums/thread-name.html (to
  index.php?p=forums&i=thread-name)

Comment: Whats your current URL structure?

Comment: @RahilWazir Everything I need to internally redirect is contained within index.php. I have some other files too, of course.

Comment: Turn on the rewrite log and look at the spew.  It is very verbose and will help you to identify where you have made your error.  If there is no spew mod_rewrite may not be available to you.

Comment: @AaronM How do I enable the rewrite log? I'm on a VPS and I've installed mod_rewrite (and it works).

Comment: Check here it depends on the version of Apache you are using. These logs are very verbose and should not be left on in a production setting. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)(\.html)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ index.php?p=$1&i=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried it. It works for the second part but not the first part. When I go on example.com/forums/, it still says 404 Not Found but example.com/forums/why-is-this-website-so-awesome-t1.html works.

Comment: Duplicate the first rule and instead of ending it with a .html end it with a /.  Cant remember if ModRewrite allows alternated groupings or you might be able to do (\.html|/)$

Comment: Ooh! I've fixed it! Basically, I had been adding the wrong slash.